# How can I protect wood and preserve its natural beauty?

Tags: wood-finish

I've had to repair a split in our dining table and, as part of that, decided to sand it all down to refinish.

I'm not entirely sure of the species. It's a hardwood, and I'm guessing tropical. It has a slight pinkish hue to it.

It was originally stained dark and, while it looked nice, we actually really like the look of the bare, non-glossy, much lighter wood now that we've sanded it.

As such, I'd like to finish it in a way that doesn't alter the color much. Would simply be applying polyurethane be enough? Are there any oils that wouldn't alter the color much and be considered food safe that you'd recommend?

Comment: I apologize, I misread the question.  Ignore my vote to close.

Comment: You should know that many woods will darken over time. Even if you finish with a clear coat the color will change slightly (although not as much as a stain would change it).

Answer (score 1):

If you like the current look of the wood, then you should not stain it, as any stain will alter the color.  2 or 3 coats of clear polyurethane will highlight the look of the wood without altering the color.

I suggest a clear, satin finish, as glossy would make your table look shiny.

Such as:
[image]

Comment: The label on your Minwax example warns that it should not be used on light wood because it can turn yellow.

Comment: Good point - be sure to check the label (I just grabbed a picture of clear poly ;) )

Comment: are all Polyurethane's prone to yellowing?

Comment: You might consider a neutral oil stain from Minwax. It will not really color the wood, but will add some depth. Then use an oil based urethane.  I have used Clear poly for years and haven't noticed any substantial yellowing even on white pine.

Comment: [Shellac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellac) and [varnish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish) have a tenancy to yellow, where as clear [polyurethane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyurethane) usually does not.

Comment: To quote from the can above, "Slight ambering may be experienced when Polyurethane is applied over light-colored wood surfaces. Always spot test on an inconspicuous area to ensure satisfactory results. For light-colored wood surfaces, we recommend protecting with Minwax® Polycrylic® Protective Finish."

Answer (score 0):

Look for an acrylic based finish whose label says it's non-yellowing. There are several brands.

Comment: Why do you recommend acrylic based finishes over other types?